# Transferring my website from PHP to Django

Tags: python, django

I'm transferring my website from PHP to Django, and now I have to make a sidebar.
I want the entries to come from the DB, and than I want them to become hyperlinks for other pages..
How can I do that?

#### nav.html

```
<nav class="menu" id="theMenu">
<div class="menu-wrap" data-spy="scroll">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.php">MY BOOKS</a></h1>
        <i class="icon-remove menu-close"></i>
            {% for question in latest_question_list %}
                <a href="{% url 'detail' slug=question.slug %}">{{ question.naslov }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
</div>
<div id="menuToggle"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>
</nav>
```

#### master2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="/static/font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/font-awesome.min.css "rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>        
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#theMenu">
        {% include "nav.html" %}           
        {% include "header2.html" %}
        {% block h1 %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/main2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Question


def index(request):
   latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
   context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
   return render(request, 'papers/index.html', context)

def detail(request, slug):
   question = Question.objects.get(slug=slug) 
   return render(request, 'papers/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,  url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', 'papers.views.index', name='index'),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w_-]+)/$', 'papers.views.detail', name='detail'),
]

 urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

#### detail.html

```
{% extends "master2.html"  %}

{% block h1 %}
<div id="g">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <h3>{{ question.naslov }}</h3> 
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="col-lg-6 desc "><p>{{ question.opsirnije_text }}</p></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 desc desc-b">
                <p>{{ question.opsirnije_text }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
{% block title  %} Detail {% endblock %}
```

Comment: the title is very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [`for` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/).

```
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
<a href="{% url 'detail' slug=question.slug %}">{{ question.naslov }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, if you want the list of questions to show up on all (or almost all) pages, you could write a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) that adds them to all contexts.

Comment: Can you tell me what would you write there?

Comment: Oh, for the template context processor? You'd write something like the `ip_address_processor` example from the documentation - but really, that's more of a thing to do when you have more than a few views. Try to get the `for` loop to work first if you haven't already.

Comment: I have put the for loop in the nav.html but nothing changes

Comment: Right, that looks reasonable. I'm sure you'll be able to get it working in no time. Good luck!